# How to sort array based on total count

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array i'm attempting to sort by the amount of total orders. I am having an issue finding a way to solve this goal. I've tried looking up examples and couldn't find a question similar to what I am attempting to do

I currently have an array of data that I am trying to sort by the largest amount of orders to the least amount of orders.

I am currently sorting by the length of the array which is not giving what I want because some orders can have a count of 10. Which would be greater then some arrays of a higher length but lower count.

How can I sort by the total of `items.amount` within the sort method?

```js
const orders = [{
        id: 242,
        items: [{
                id: '3000',
                amount: 2
            },
            {
                id: '3001',
                amount: 1
            },
            {
                id: '3002',
                amount: 4
            }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 1,
        items: [{
            id: '3000',
            amount: 10
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        items: [{
                id: '3211',
                amount: 3
            },
            {
                id: '3000',
                amount: 1
            }
        ]
    }
]


const sortedOrders = orders.sort(
      (taskA, taskB) =>
       
        taskB.items.length - taskA.items.length
    );

console.log(sortedOrders)
```

I am expecting an output like this with `amount: 10` being the greatest value so displaying first:

```
[
  {
    "id": 242,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "items": [
              {
                "id": "3000",
                "amount": 10
              }
            ]
          },
      {
        "id": "3000",
        "amount": 2
      },
      {
        "id": "3001",
        "amount": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "3002",
        "amount": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "3211",
        "amount": 3
      },
      {
        "id": "3000",
        "amount": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your text says it want to sort on (a value derived from) `amount` but your code sorts on `items.length`. One of those two is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create a function that returns the sum of all amounts for the given order,

For example,

```
function totalAmount(order) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < order.items.length; i++) {
        sum += order.items[i].amount;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Now all we have to do is call this function inside our sort and we will be sorting based on the difference between the result of `totalAmount` for `taskA` and `taskB`.

```
const sortedOrders = orders.sort(
      (taskA, taskB) =>
       totalAmount(taskB) - totalAmount(taskA)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to get the count of all the amounts in each item array and then sort it in descending order based on the count by using [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) compare method to get the result in reverse order.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const orders = [{
  id: 242,
  items: [{
    id: '3000',
    amount: 2
  }, {
    id: '3001',
    amount: 1
  }, {
    id: '3002',
    amount: 4
  }]
}, {
  id: 1,
  items: [{
    id: '3000',
    amount: 10
  }]
}, {
  id: 14,
  items: [{
    id: '3211',
    amount: 3
  }, {
    id: '3000',
    amount: 1
  }]
}];

const res = orders.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push({
    ...curr,
    itemsCount: curr.items.reduce((sum, { amount }) => sum + amount, 0)
  })
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res.sort((a,b) => b.itemsCount - a.itemsCount));
```